# Solr join and get field from both entity in single core

Tags: spring-mvc, solr, solrj, solr4

I am using two entity 1) Title and 2) ApprovalForm in single core. Here i have to retrieve both entity fields.

```
select t.TitleNo,ap.PlanNumber 
  From  titles as t join approvalform as ap
  on t.TitleNo = ap.TitleNumber;
```

1) Entity:Title

```
 <entity name="Titles" pk="id" dataSource="TitlesDB" query="select 'Titles' as SolrSource, TitleNo as id, TitleNo,
             Authors from titles>
     <field column="SolrSource" name="SolrSource"/>
     <field column="TitleNo" name="TitleNo"/>
      <field column="Authors" name="Authors"/>
        .....
</entity>
```

2) Entity: ApprovalForm

```
      <entity name="ApprovalForm" pk="id" dataSource="TitlesDB" query="select 'approvalform' as SolrSource, TitleNumber as id, 
             planNumber from titles>
     <field column="SolrSource" name="SolrSource"/>
     <field column="TitleNumber" name="TitleNumber"/>
      <field column="planNumber" name="planNumber"/>
      ..............
</entity>
```

Join query  is :

```
     {!join from =TitleNo to = TitleNumber}
```

Here i want to select planNumber. ie., How can i select second entity table fields.

Comment: SOLR join unlike DB join we can retrieve results only from second "to" entity. Hope I have got your question correct

Comment: yes.. i want to select some fields from second entity..

Comment: The way we do for DB, we cannot fetch values from both the tables in SOLR after the join. Consider SOLR join as inline query. Eg: select * from table_a where table_a.id in (select table_a_id from table_b). The way we cannot select columns from table_b, in SOLR too we cannot fetch values from driving record. What we can do with SOLR join is, filter certain records from SOLR, then pass one field out of that records and again lookup in another field. Hope this time I answered you correctly.